# Connecting UICollectionView to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview

I'm quite new to SO. I'm trying to populate a collection view with data from a Firebase Database. The Users var that fetches data from Firebase comes back right with all the data. What I'm trying to figure out why my `UICollectionView` comes back with `Nil`. I think the crash happens in this line:

```
self.usersCollectionView.reloadData()
```

and the error is:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Its my `collectionView` var that's returning a `nil`.

I have connected the cell class to the cell.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class UserCollectionController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var cellIdentifier = "User Cell"

    var users = [User]()

    @IBOutlet weak var usersCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    func createAlert(title: String, message: String) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func fetchUser() {

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").observe(FIRDataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                let user = User()

                user.name = dictionary["name"] as! String?
                user.profileImageURL = dictionary["profileImageURL"] as! String?

                self.users.append(user)

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                    self.usersCollectionView.reloadData()

                })


            }

            print(snapshot)

        }, withCancel: nil)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchUser()

    }


    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return  users.count
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! UserCollectionViewCell

        let cellUsers = users[indexPath.item]

        //cell.users = users[indexPath.item]

        cell.usersNameLabel.text = cellUsers.name

        if let profileImageURL = cellUsers.profileImageURL {


            cell.usersImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: profileImageURL)
        }

        return cell
    }


    public func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }
}

class UserCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var usersImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var usersNameLabel: UILabel!
    /*
    // MARK: - Public API
    var users: User! {

        didSet {

            updateUI()

        }

    }

    // MARK: - Private

    //@IBOutlet weak var featuredImageView: UIImageView!
    //@IBOutlet weak var interestTitleLabel: UILabel!

    func updateUI() {

        if let profileImage = users.profileImageURL {

            self.usersImageView?.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: profileImage)

        }

        usersNameLabel?.text! = users.name!

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    */

}
```

This is my `User` var:

```
import UIKit

class User: NSObject {

    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var password: String?
    var profileImageURL: String?

}
```

If there is any questions about my code or if you need more info. Please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Can you try to see what happens when you change FIRDataEventType.childAdded to FIRDataEventType.value?

Comment: Thanks Jordi. My code works actually. Its my UICollectionView that doesnt show the cells with the details. Sorry, I thought it was the connection to the database that was not working. I did a print(User) and it printed the users on the console.

Comment: It seems like your collectionView is not created properly. How have you connected it in storyboard?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, It wasn't created properly. I redid my code coz it was messy and now It works. I believe I missed a step when I created my collectionView. Now I got it to work. Thanks. Im still in the process of figuring it out what happened.

Comment: Happens to the best of us! I've added it as an answer as well if you want to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your collectionView is not created properly. How have you connected it in storyboard?

You're trying to reload the collectionView before it's been properly set.

Comment: I am new as well, how do you connect it in the storyboard?